# Merge two tables with same id

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame like this:

```
df1:
    X1  X2   X3
1    1   4    7
2    2   5    8
3    3   6    9

class(df1[1,"X1"])
```

[1] "character"

Now I have another data frame like this:

```
df2:
    id    name
1     1       A
2     2       C
3     3       B
4     4       Z
5     5       X
6     6       G
7     7       E
8     8       Y
9     9       H
```

the id here is numeric

Every character in df1 are the same as number in df2.
This is the result I need:

```
    X1  X2   X3
1    A   Z    E
2    C   X    Y
3    B   G    H
```

I know that you can merge two tables with the same key, but in this case, my key on df1 is the data in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` for this

```
df1[] <-  lapply(df1, function(x) df2$name[match(x, df2$id)])
df1
#   X1 X2 X3
#1  A  Z  E
#2  C  X  Y
#3  B  G  H
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you :) Though I am not too familiar with lapply function

Comment: @Ching  It is just alike a `for` loop, only difference is that we have more control on it.  It is advantageous in certain situations